# Vue Router route query param added by beforeEnter lost after navigate into the same route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When navigating into the same route you are currently at, the route query `page` added by the **before enter route guard** is lost.

This is due to the fact that router link `to` object does not contain query `page`, and it does not go into  **before enter hook** anymore, since it is already in the same route.

I figured out that you can add it in your router push or link button and you need to add this whenever you know the view contain query `page`.

Example:

`this.$router.push({ name: 'routeName', query: { page: 1 } });`

### Question:

Is there an elegant way to handle this in route guard?

Which hook should I use so that route query `page` can be kept even user navigate into the same route?

### Example code:

Route

```js
// Sample route
const routes =  [
  {
    path: 'test',
    name: 'Test',
    component: TestPage,
    beforeEnter: testPageGuard,
  },
];
```

Route Guard

```js
// Test Page Guard
testPageGuard: (to, from, next) => {
  const { page = null } = to.query;  
  let finalNext;

  if (!page) {
    finalNext = {
      ...to,
      query: {
        ...to.query,
        page: 1,
      },
    };
  }

  if (finalNext) {
    next(finalNext);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

View

```js
// TestPage.vue
<template>
  <!-- The problem can be reproduce when clicking this link 
       when you are already in route '/test'               -->
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'Test'}">
    Test
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Test',
};
</script>
```

### Solution Figured:

- Add query **page** to router link

```js
// TestPage.vue
<template>
  <!-- query page is added here -->
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'Test', query: { page: 1 } }">
    Test
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>...</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that there are two more ways to do this.

## **Solution 1: Update at "beforeRouteUpdate" Hook**

**beforeRouteUpdate** triggers when query param changes even when in the same route.

Hence we can remove the **beforeEnter** guard and the extra `page` query in the route link, and do query param `page` adding at that particular page.

### Example Code

View

```js
// TestPage.vue
<template>
  <!-- The problem can be reproduce when clicking this link 
       when you are already in route '/test'               -->
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'Test'}">
    Test
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Test',

  // Solution here
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(to.query, 'page')) {
      next({
        ...to,
        query: {
          // This line is used to retain other query if there is any
          ...to.query,
          page: 1,
        },
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

## **Solution 2: Update at "beforeEach" Hook**

When query param changes even when in the same route, it actually go through **beforeEach** hook also.

Hence we can remove the **beforeEnter** guard and the extra `page` query in the route link.

Add meta tag `hasQueryParamPage` for that route and do query param `page` adding in the global **beforeEach** hook.

This design has better reusability if you have other pages that require the query param `page`.

### Example Code

Route

```js
// Sample route
const routes =  [
  {
    path: 'test',
    name: 'Test',
    component: TestPage,
    // add meta tag
    meta: { hasQueryParamPage: true },
  },
];
```

Router

```js
// router.js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
...
});

// Solution here
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => (record.meta.hasQueryParamPage))) {
    let updatedNext = null;

    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(to.query, 'page')) {
      updatedNext = {
        ...to,
        query: {
          // This line is used to retain other query if there is any
          ...to.query,
          page: 1,
        },
      };
    }
    
    if (updatedNext) {
      next(updatedNext);
      return;
    }
  }

  next();
});
```